# I need help to reshape the output file the way I want

Tags: python

I have a file that contains two tables. I want to extract the values of the first table from the those of the second and write them on another file.

There are four columns, the first column is the symbols, the second, third and forth columns contain the values I want to subtract from one another. I want the values to be listed following one another.

This is my python3 script.

```
def read_xyz_file(file_path, start_line=2, end_line=None):
    """Reads an XYZ file amd returns a list of atomic coordinates"""
    atomic_coordinates=[]
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines=file.readlines()[start_line-1:end_line]
        num_atoms=int(lines[0])
        for line in lines[1:]:
            line=line.split()
            x=float(line[1])
            y=float(line[2])
            z=float(line[3])
            atomic_coordinates.append([x,y,z])
        return atomic_coordinates

def subtract_coordinates(file1_path, file2_path, output_path):
    """Subtract coordinates from file2 from coordinates in file1 and writes the results to file3"""
    file1_coordinates=read_xyz_file(file1_path, start_line=3101, end_line=3124)
    file2_coordinates=read_xyz_file(file2_path, start_line=3125, end_line=3148)

    if len(file1_coordinates) !=len(file2_coordinates):
        print("Error: Number oof atoms in file1 is not the same.")
        return

    num_atoms=23

    with open(output_path, 'w') as file3:
        file3.write(str(num_atoms)+"\n")
        file3.write("Coordinates subtracted from file2-file1\n")
        for i in range(num_atoms):
            x_diff=file2_coordinates[i][0]-file1_coordinates[i][0]
            y_diff=file2_coordinates[i][1]-file1_coordinates[i][1]
            z_diff=file2_coordinates[i][2]-file1_coordinates[i][2]
            file3.write("""{:.6f}\n""".format(x_diff)
                        """{:.6f}\n""".format(y_diff)
                        """{:.6f}\n""".format(z_diff))

file1_path="TS6-int-IRC-1.xyz"
file2_path="TS6-int-IRC-1.xyz"
output_path="file3.xyz"
subtract_coordinates(file1_path, file2_path, output_path)
```

When I run this code, I got a list. But on the list, the values obtained from the first line is listed, then the second line, so on. However, I want the values on the second column listed first, followed by the values of the third column so on.

Example input:

file1:

| A | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 25 | 11 | 6 |
| C | 12 | 10 | 5 |
| C | 5 | 2 | 1 |

file2:

| A | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C | 32 | 10 | 6 |
| C | 14 | 6 | 1 |
| C | 2 | 8 | 7 |

output I want (in a column, not in a row):

```
7.
2.
-3.
-1.
-4.
6.
0.
-1.
6.
```

output I get (in a column, not in a row):

```
7.
-1.
0.
2.
-4.
1.
-3.
6.
6.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/). We will not write code to specification for you here. Plagiarism is a serious academic offense; aside from that, we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and analyze the task, identify the logical steps to solve the problem, and figure out *where you are actually stuck*. Make sure to check if the issue is already addressed in another question.

Comment: It [is not possible to "help you"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/) here as this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score -2):

Change the cycles you use to produce the outputs, currently you use a cycle that loops over atoms and produces a triad of outputs for each atom. Instead, you should first select a column, and then loop over atoms to get the outputs for that column.

So your processing loop should look like:

```py
with open(output_path, 'w') as file3:
    file3.write(str(num_atoms)+"\n")
    file3.write("Coordinates subtracted from file2-file1\n")
    for column in range(3): # iterate through a column at a time
        for i in range(num_atoms):
            diff=file2_coordinates[i][column]-file1_coordinates[i][column]
            file3.write("""{:.6f}\n""".format(diff))
```